# Probability distribution "similar" to Gaussian.

Tags: probability, measure-theory, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Does there exist a distribution A other than Gaussian such that:
1)  linear combination of random variable from A is distribution A 
2) easy to integrate, for example find entropy

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

The solutions of 1) are [the stable distributions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stable_distribution). Except for the Cauchy distribution, I don't think there is an analytic form of the Entropy.